# bash: dealing with filenames in pipes and IFR

Tags: bash

My situation is that I have an ancient directory full of files in which an equally ancient (and poorly written) application creates files.  Over the years hundreds of files have been created with leading, trailing or embedded whitespace or other "special" characters.  I want to clean this mess up.

I can generate a list of the actively used files.  I can compare the active files against the complete list of existing files and generate a list of the non-active files.  I now want to delete the non-active files.  My problem is that looping over the list of files seems to ignore the `IFR` setting.

```
ACTIVE=`/bin/mktemp -t`
NON_ACTIVE=`/bin/mktemp -t`

...generate active file list... > $ACTIVE

/bin/ls -1 /path/to/all/files | \
    /bin/grep -Fxvf $ACTIVE > $NON_ACTIVE
```

I now want to delete the files listed in `$NON_ACTIVE`.  I have tried setting

```
IFR=$(/bin/echo -en '\n\b')
```

before using

```
/bin/rm `/bin/cat $NON_ACTIVE`
```

or a `for` loop to loop over the list and remove each file.  I have not yet found the magic to let me whack the poorly names files.  Ideas?

I suppose that I could edit `$NON_ACTIVE` and prepend `rm` to each line and enclose each messy file name in single quotes but I would like to script the whole process -- and learn (or relearn) something in the way.

Comment: It's `IFS`, not `IFR`.

Comment: Using `ls` in scripts is another bad practice; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: ...and if you want to compare two lists, the right tool is `comm`, not `grep`. See FAQ #36: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036

Comment: Also, you can't safely use pipes to delimit filenames, since valid UNIX filenames can contain pipe symbols. Use NUL characters as delimiters, and arrays to store them (since NULs also can't be stored inside string variables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach that works with the full range of possible filenames, including when there are more names than will fit on a single command line:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ^-- needed because this uses bash-only features (particularly, bash 4.0 or newer)

# build an associative array with names of active files as keys
declare -A active_files-( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  active_files[$filename]=1
done < <(program_that_lists_active_files_with_NUL_delimiters)

# build a regular array of inactive files
inactive_files=( )
for file in *; do
  [[ ${active_files[$file]} ]] || inactive_files+=( "$file" )
done

# if you want to do only one rm call, and work with lists too long to fit on a single
# rm command line...
xargs -0 -- rm -f -- < <(printf '%s\0' "${inactive_files[@]}")
```

If you don't care about working with really long lists of inactive files, the last line can be replaced with this shorter alternative:

```
rm -f -- "${inactive_files[@]}"
```

Comment: Actually my solution was one mentioned in the ParsingLs link above.  I switched to perl and am done and happy.  Thanks